# Listening for a page change event

Tags: jquery

I Iam working with Jquery and all I am trying to do is to print some value on console everytime pagination happens on table and want to perform some task on `td`. It works on first page

Below is my code

```
$('table tr').each(function(index) {
$('table tr').find('td').css('background','red');
});
```

is the code working fine. but In order to make it work I need to make sure it executes after document is ready and with following code, this is not even working on first page

```
 $(document).on('ready', 'table tr', function(){
                                  $('table tr').each(function(index) {
    $('table tr').find('td').css('background','red');
    });
                            });
```

help will be apericated

Comment: The `change` event is used when the `value` of a  form control is amended, it's not relevant for `tr`. Are you using a library to manage pagination of the table? If so it's likely that raises an event you can hook to. Check the documentation

Comment: If you're not using library, can you post the code of the pagination?

Comment: I see you've edited the code in the question, but now it's far less relevant than it was before as you're not showing any attempt to hook to an event handler...?

Comment: I am using https://datatables.net/

Comment: let me make a clear edit

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please check, If need more information, do let me know

Comment: Hook to the `page` event: https://datatables.net/reference/event/page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when ever I am using `page.dt` or `draw.dt` it even stops working on first page

Comment: In which case you're doing something wrong. The docs are pretty clear. Check the console for errors